# SQL JOIN from other JOIN

Tags: sql, join

So, this is probably gonna sound like a weird or dumb question.

I have this application that I'm writing, which consists of four tables. Two are 'connected' to one main table, and one last one is connected to one of those two tables. I've included a database diagram to give you a better idea of what I mean.

Now, my goal is to have 'Bedrijfsnaam' from the 'Bedrijven' table into the 'Samenwerkingen' table. Problem is: I can't add more than two foreign keys, so I was assuming that I would have to create a FK in'Contactpersonen' table and pick it from the 'Bedrijven' table. It would basically mean I'd have a JOIN in 'Contactpersonen' table to my 'Bedrijven' table. And then the 'Samenwerkingen' table has a JOIN to the 'Contactpersonen' table and accesses the column from 'Bedrijven'.

Does that make any sense? Hope it does, because I could really use some help making this possible. xD

[image: Database design]

Comment: You can do that but it is a bit complex and unnecessary I guess. Possibly this link can help some https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493780/do-you-absolutely-need-foreign-keys-in-a-database. I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Samenwerkingen` has a foreign key to `Contactpersonen` which is itself related to `Bedrijven`, you don't need an additional constraint: your data integrity is guaranteed and you can join the two tables.

Your query should look like :

```
select s.*, b.* from Samenwerkingen s 
       inner join Contactpersonen c on s.Contactpersonen = c.Contactpersonen 
       inner join Bedrijven b on c.Bedrijfnaam = b.Bedrijfnaam
```

Comment: That did indeed work. Didn't realize it'd be so simple. :P Anyway, thank you!